# NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable in class ContextCompat; or its super classes declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How can i fix?

app.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*****"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 5
        versionName "2.1.1"
        multiDexEnabled true;
    }
--
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    compile project(path: ':libs:AlexaAndroid')
    compile project(path: ':libs:RecorderLevelView')
    compile project(path: ':libs:speechutils-master')
    compile project(path: ':libs:pulsator4droid')
    compile project(path: ':libs:MaterialRippleLayout')
    compile project(path: ':libs:ListViewAnimations-core')
    compile files('--/libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
    compile files('--/libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('--/libs/listviewanimations_lib-manipulation_3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('--/libs/listviewanimations_lib-core-slh_3.1.0.jar')
    compile files('--/libs/android-support-v4.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
}
-- shows jar file path.
```

ERROR LOG

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable(Landroid/content/Context;I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.***.***.***-1/base.apk)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                                                                                  at com.***.***.***.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:70)
                                                                                  at com.***.***.***.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Activity's super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) gives me an error:
Application working fine with ADB Device or if i use usb debugging on device then its working fine but its not working with release apk.

I am not sure is i made any gradle updates, i compared with old version its not showing any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this problem.

In project had library ie `compile files('--/libs/listviewanimations_lib-core-slh_3.1.0.jar')` in its lib folder exist `com.android.support:support-v4.jar` file so gradle refer its jar and gives error `NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable in class ContextCompat; or its super classes declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat'` becasue getDrawable function not declared in to `com.android.support:support-v4.jar` file.

After removing `com.android.support:support-v4.jar` from lib folder and clean, rebuild my android project and synchronized with gradle and its work for me.

Comment: Where is the `lib` folder you're talking about?

Comment: @Brett long time back was working on an android project, in the library already the same jar included hence was getting the error.